# Align text with picture in Android

Tags: android

I'm new on Android.

How can I align a textView with the center of an ImageView using a relative layout?

I have try the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="15dp"
    android:maxWidth="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
    android:text="Counter" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

but the text is not aligned with the center of the picture.

Thanks!

Comment: The best approach is to add your image as a compound drawable in your TextView, instead of using an ImageView. i.e.: `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_alignTop and layout_alignBottom to align the top and bottom of the textview to the imageview.  Then make sure the text has center gravity.  This should align it to the middle.  ( I believe it should be the right gravity by default, but forcing it never hurts).

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout children can use:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to align your textview between the borders of your imageviews top and bottom. And also be sure to center your textview's gravity, so that it will just centered inside your imageview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="15dp"
    android:maxWidth="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Counter" />
```

For a better approach, IMHO, add your imageview to your textview as a drawableLeft, so that it will represent much more to user.